# Why is `i` allowed to exist after `for i in` loop

Tags: python, iterator

I just realized that

```
for i in range(5):
    pass

print(i)
# >>> 4
```

And it caused a bug for me in a different situation. I always thought that `i` should disappear after the for loop.

Any explanation why it shouldn't?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the referred answer for the duplicate question. This is interesting.